# Best practices when starting a new project

Tags: visual-studio

When you first fire up Visual Studio, or even before that (Hopefully)
What do you consider best practices when starting a new project?

Different things I have done in the past

- Consider the technology choices
- Attempt to identify the potential bottlenecks/brickwalls
- Throw away the specification
- Ask lots and lots of questions
- Launched straight into code! (who hasn't?)

As programmers we should be methodical in our approach.
What do you do when starting a new project?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(If applicable) Figure out whether you are building a throwaway prototype, an expandable prototype, or a final production system.

I think that a major problem with a lot of projects is that people don't get this one figured out to begin with. They either over-engineer and the project doesn't deliver on time, or they write throwaway code that later becomes too expensive to throw away.

Comment: True, I hate that moment when you realise that your boss thinks your prototype is a production level program.  When the cost of making it production doesn't bring noticable changes (Read - visible)

Comment: The problem with programs is like they're poker chips. Once you've sunk some into the pot, you end up chasing when you should fold...

Answer (score 6):

**Start using version control right away.**

It is always frustrating building prototype "throwaway code" that eventually gets thrown away - and then realizing that some of that code would be really really useful to have.

Comment: I hope these days Version Control is just a given

Answer (score 2):

I do the following when building for others.  WHen I build myself using more agile dev concepts, I still cycle through these steps.   It makes it very easy to involve others as well.

**Analyze:** What do we need to do and why.  Aka feature spec.

**Design:** what are we going to build, how will it work, and why?  aka. Technical Spec.

**Plan:** What and who do we need, when, to do what

**Implement:** Build, test, repeat.

**Launch:** Almost there.

**Support/Document/Train, etc:** In case you get hit by a bus, or someone arranges for it.

Answer (score 1):

[Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_(development))

++

1. Requirements Gathering
2. Scope
3. Out of Scope
4. Pick Platform to deliver on and appropriate Development Environment
5. Calculate Expenses, Make budget
6. Schedule
7. Review at each stage and educate the end user of what is being made throughout

[easy tips](http://www.projectkickstart.com/downloads/tips10-project-management-best-practices.cfm)

Answer (score 0):

Create my first test project.

Answer (score 0):

One main thing I always like to know is, who exactly is doing what! even from the starting point. Stops alot of time being lost.